# Solving a matrix differential equation with Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I need to solve this equation in Mathematica:

> d/dx **v**(x) = **A** . **v**(x)

here **v** is the **column vector** `{v1(x),v2(x),v3(x),v4(x)}` and 
**A** is a **4 x 4 matrix**. 
I want to solve for the functions `v1, v2, v3, v4` with any initial conditions. 
The range of x is from 0 to 1000.

How do I write Mathematica code for this type of differential equation using `NDSolve`?

Comment: It might be worth asking this question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, if you have some horrible matrix

```
A =  RandomReal[0.1, {4, 4}]; (* A horrible matrix *)
```

which we make anti-symmetric (so the solution is oscillatory)

```
A = A - Transpose@A;
```

Define the vector of functions and their initial conditions

```
v[x_] := {v1[x], v2[x], v3[x], v4[x]};

init = v[0] == RandomReal[1, 4]
```

Then the `NDSolve` command looks like

```
sol = NDSolve[LogicalExpand[v'[x] == A.v[x] && init], 
        {v1, v2, v3, v4}, {x, 0, 1000}]
```

And the solutions can be plotted with

```
Plot[Evaluate[v[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1000}]
```

[image: da plot]

---

Note that that the above differential equation is a linear, first order equation with constant coefficients, so is simply solved using a matrix exponential. 
However, if the matrix `A` was a function of `x`, then analytic solutions become hard, but the numerical code stays the same.

For example, try:

```
A = RandomReal[1/10, {4, 4}] - Exp[-RandomReal[1/100, {4, 4}] x^2];
A = A - Transpose@A;
```

Which can produce solutions like

[image: more]

Comment: wow! Thaaaaanks a Lot ! great job :) 
My Horrible matrix is a function of x. Thank god you said that the numerical code remains the same ! :P 
One more suggestion needed. Can you refer me a good book book for mathematica?

Comment: @Mush: A solid and recent book is [Mathematica In Action](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0387753664/). But the Mathematica documentation is also really good, there's lots of hidden gems in there. Finally, there's this site - some good Mathematica programmers around here (including a few WRI employees). See the big list posted at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8672115/421225

Comment: @Mush: btw, if my post answered your question, don't forget to press the checkmark button to accept it.

Comment: @PlatoManiac: You probably shouldn't link to illegal copies of books. Link to Sal's homepage instead, or to Amazon, since stackexchange automatically affiliates those links.

Comment: @Simon Sorry for the ethical mistake. But I have been kind of Piratebay guy. Still here is the book I meant http://www.amazon.com/Mathematica-Cookbook-Sal-Mangano/dp/0596520999

Comment: @Simon: what if you had a variable dimension (n instead of 4), how would you define `v[x_] := {v1[x], v2[x], v3[x], v4[x]};`. I thought of `Table[v[i][x],{i,1,n}];` but it does not seem to do what I am looking for.

Comment: I managed to generalise it, my initial attempt finally works (using a table of function).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same with a matrix instead of a vector v. As long as equation for it can be read correctly without knowing that this symbol represents a vector or a matrix, NDSolve deduced its character from initial condition, however in case when dimensionality of variable is explicit:

```
M'[t]==a[t]*IdentityMatrix[2]+M[t]
```

it fails.
An "ordinary" solution is to define matrix explicitly and flatten it when giving as a list of variables.

However I omitted this issue (and many relatex syntax problems) just introducing a reduntant variable which only role is to be the identity matrix but without introducing a list (matrix is 2d list, so Mathematica acts as while adding lists to each other, generating the error):

```
eqn = {w'[t] == a[t]*identity[t] + w[t], a'[t] == 2, identity'[t] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
init={ w[0] == {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, a[0] == 1, identity[0] == {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}


sol = NDSolve[eqn&&init, {w, a, identity}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Some evidence of work:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[w[t] /. sol][[1, 1, 1]], Evaluate[w[t] /. sol][[1, 1, 2]]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I do not have Mathematica on my home notebook :))

```
NDSolve[Transpose[{v1[x],v2[x],v3[x],v4[x]}']=={{a11,a12,a13,a14},{a21,a22,a23,a24},{a31,a32,a33,a34},{a41,a42,a43,a44}}.Transpose[{v1[x],v2[x],v3[x],v4[x]}], {v1,v2,v3,v4},{x,0,1000}]
```

ps: you can rewrite it in a different way, replacing your record as a set of equations
{v1'[x]==a11*v1[x]+a12*v2[x]+a13*v3[x]+a14*v4[x],v2'[x]==a21*v1[x]+a22*v2[x]+a23*v3[x]+a24*v4[x], and so on..} if you want )

Comment: Thanks Cherry. But my matrix **A** horrible. i cant put its elements a11,a22... by hand :(. After some operation i get a  matrix. So i need to use that result directly. will it work well if just write A instead of elements? :-s

Comment: @Mush          Try it as in my first example - I will be near Mathematica only tomorrow :) And if you have A matrix, you do not need to rewrite its elements - you can access them directly, like A[[1]][[2]] will give you a12

Comment: @Cheery: In your first code block, you accidentally used `*` instead of `.`.

Comment: @Simon         It doesn't matter here. {{a, b}, {c, d}}.{x, y} or {{a, b}, {c, d}}*{x, y} records are the same.

Comment: @Cheery: Sorry, but that is definitely not true. The first is the dot product and gives `{a x + b y, c x + d y}`, but the second command is called the Hadamard product, it returns `{{a x, b x}, {c y, d y}}`.

Comment: @Simon I do not have Mathematica right now (at 5 AM :)), but wolframalpha gives the same answer. Oh, it thinks about "the fools" and replaced automatically * to . )) Sorry, I definitely have to sleep. Thanks for the hint.